# passing a function as a string in php

Tags: php

I'm just starting to learn PHP and am using the W3 Schools tut. In the error handling section there is this code:

```
<?php
function customError($errno,$errstr) {
    echo '<b>Error:</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />';
}
set_error_handler('customError');

echo($test);
?>
```

Why is the customError() function being passed as a string? Is this a mistake in the tut?
Also, why isnt `$test` defined?

Comment: Do you have a link for this tut?

Comment: Use *any* other tutorial for learning. See under "callback" in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php

Comment: @aspect http://w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp

Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @codeninja: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). w3schools has an utterly miserable quality reputation, and are only "big" because they've spent a lot of time/money to force themselves to the top of google search results.

Comment: The code is not correct in more than ways I've given characters in comments box to list. I hardly doubt it is any tutorial ever published on W3 School. Furthermore, there is php.net/ to answer beginner questions. Refer to php.net/set_error_handler

Comment: imo, if you want to learn something new, would not the official documentation is much better? http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

Comment: I don't see why this is being downvoted. It's a perfectly valid question (although w3schools is an abysmal site and should never be used.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the customError() function being passed as a string?

For the same reason that [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) or [`ob_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) take strings for function specifiers. PHP just needs the name of the function. A function name not enclosed in quotes with either try being executed as a constant or (if followed by parenthesis) will be executed and the result passed to the function.

Because of the way PHP *parses* documents for execution, you have to work within the means of the language (use strings instead of "pointers" to function calls).

> Also, why isnt $test defined?

This is a purposeful call to trigger an error. They are trying to get you to work with an undefined variable so an error occurs and the code you just wrote (with the custom handling) catches the error.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not an error. It's not so common, but some standard PHP functions accept functions name as parameter when you have to pass a function for same reason. `set-error-handler` is one of these function.

If you are curios about that, you can read here:

<s>`http://it2.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback`</s>(dead link)

Answer (score 0):

The `set_error_handler` method takes a string as its first parameter -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php this is the function invoked for errors

The `echo($test)` causes an error to be thrown thus invoking the `customError` function

Answer (score 0):

Because `customError` is not actually being passed as a string, per se, but rather its name is being passed as a string to PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php , it allows you to specify a custom error handler function to PHP.